# How do I remove document.write in html output?

Tags: html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My HTML</title>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    document.write("Hello World");
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

How Do I remove the document.write part of the output? My chrome output is document.write("Hello World");

I just want to output Hello World on Chrome.

Comment: you could try to enclose your js code within `script` tag
`<script>document.write(); var name="abc";</script>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the closing script tag to be after the document.write("Hello World") so that the document.write() is encased within the script tag. e.g.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>My HTML</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write("Hello World");
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```